# Jasmine test event listener function for nodeList from given selector

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have following code which listens for keydown event in given array of nodeList.

```
var obj = {
 method: function(nodeSelector) {
    var nodeContainers = document.querySelectorAll(nodeSelector);
    var keyListenerFunc = this.keyListener.bind(this);

    this.bindListener(nodeContainers, keyListenerFunc);
  },
  isListNode: function (evt){
    return evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'li';
  },
  isContainer: function(evt){
    return evt.target.parentNode.classList.contains(this.indicatorClass);
  },
  keyListener: function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 32 && (this.isContainer(evt) && this.isListNode(evt))) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.target.click();
    }
  },
  bindListener: function(targets, callbackFunc) {
    [].forEach.call(targets, function(item) {
      item.addEventListener('keydown', callbackFunc);
    });
  },
  indicatorClass: 'indicator'
};
```

I'm using it like:  `obj.method('.someClassNames');`
But now I want to test it completely including the triggering of keydown event. How can I attach event listener and then trigger keydown event on given dom nodes so that my Jasmine tests would work ? How can I create some dummy html code here and then trigger event on it ? I am expecting to write tests of this type =>

```
it('It should put event listeners on each carousel passed to the service', function(){});
it('It should call event.preventDefault', function(){});
it('It should call event.target.click', function(){});
```

My markup is follwing

```
var html = '<div class="someClassNames">'+
    '<div class="indicator">'+
      '<li>text</li>'+
    '</div>'
  '</div>';
```

I am assuming that I am going to need to trigger following keydown event but I am not sure as to how to trigger is on the given markup and check in the test description.

```
var e = new window.KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      bubbles: true
});
Object.defineProperty(e, 'keyCode', {'value': 32});
```

I am very much new to testing with Jasmine and I couldn't find any examples that would help me test this scenario. I hope my example makes it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few observations:

- Note that the callbackFunc is actually assigned to the onkeydown
  attribute of the element. Hence you may want to spy on the
  element.onkeydown rather than obj.keyListener
- Sometimes the render of the UI element may take place after spec has
  been run.
- So to ensure that you have the element is present, I've used the
  setTimeout with a jasmine [clock](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions)
- If you really want to test your obk.keyListener, try using an
  anonymous function like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Event_Listener_with_anonymous_function)

here is how I've it running. I've used mouseover as I'm lazy :)

```
var obj = {
    testVar : "Object",
  method: function(nodeSelector) {
    var nodeContainers = document.querySelectorAll(nodeSelector);
    var keyListenerFunc = this.keyListener.bind(this);
    this.bindListener(nodeContainers, keyListenerFunc);
  },
  isListNode: function(evt) {
    return evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'li';
  },
  isContainer: function(evt) {
    return evt.target.parentNode.classList.contains(this.indicatorClass);
  },
  keyListener: function(evt) {
    console.log('Yo! You hovered!');    
  },
  bindListener: function(targets, callbackFunc) {
    targets.forEach(function(item) {
      item.addEventListener('mouseover', callbackFunc, false);
    });
  },
  indicatorClass: 'indicator'
};

describe('Sample tests', function() {
//this ensures you have the element set up 
  beforeEach(function() {
  jasmine.clock().install();
  jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 200;
    setTimeout(function() {
      obj.method('div.indicator');
    }, 0);
  });

  it('It should put event listeners', function() {
    jasmine.clock().tick(10);
    var ele= document.getElementsByClassName("indicator")[0];
    spyOn(ele, 'onmouseover').and.callThrough();    
    $('.indicator').trigger('mouseover');    
    expect(ele.onmouseover).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(typeof ele.onmouseover).toBe('function'); 
  });
});
```

HTML CONTENT:

```
<div class="someClassNames">
  <div class="indicator">
    <li>text</li>
    <br/> </div>
</div>
```